# Access Form with multiple tab controls

Tags: ms-access, database-design, reporting

This is not a developer question, it's a novice question from someone that has used Access as a front-end for a SQL database for years with no problems.  I've now created a standalone Access database that I've created for various staff to fill out different pages of a three page form.  The form has control tabs for pages 1, 2 and 3.  Each page has the social security (SS) number of an individual on it.  Pages 2 and 3 are just memo fields except for the SS number.  I have created 4 records for individuals.  When I try to print or do a print preview from the form, it shows just the first page for each individual.  If I save it as a report, it does the same thing.

How can I get three pages to print for each individual, or just print three pages on one individual?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would separate your reports from your user interface.  That way your report can be exactly what you need rather than making a duel purpose form.

Comment: I agree. Forms for data entry, reports for output.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the report wizards to build a custom report, then how about removing the tab control and building a long (vertical) form with all the fields in it in three sections, with a vertical scrollbar.  Then the print should work.

Comment: If I build a long form, it will only go to 22 inches.  That's all access will allow in forms and reports, so I would have to scrunch the fields all together and they would not format correctly when printed.  By three sections I assume you mean page breaks?

Comment: Yes.  But if you have that much info, what is your objection to building a 'real' report using a report wizard?  Once you've done that, all you need to do is add a button to the form to print it, with one tiny change to the vbcode that the wizard uses for the button.